# How to add gradient transparency mask in final cut pro x?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I want to add a gradient transparency mask so that the front layer will slowly transform into the layer below. Can anybody suggest something?

I'm not talking about transition in time, but transition between layers. This is an example of video I want to get:
[image]

I think that in old final cut you could do this with black to white gradient and filters.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you ever found a solution, but FCPX does have a Graduated Mask that works.

To use it:

1. Position clip1 over clip2 on the timeline.
2. Add the "Graduate Mask" filter to clip1.
3. Animate both "Center" and "Target" properties of the effect to move left to right.

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain how to set up the transform as requested? Without that, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Nice tip. Here's the explanation. Position clip1 over clip2 on the timeline. Add "Graduate Mask" to clip1. Then animate both "Center" and "Target" properties of the effect to move left to right.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking a special, unique transition that you can't find in the effect browser, you have to use Motion to create the transition yourself, and publish it to FCPX.  If you're just looking for a slow dissolve, there's already a dissolve transition available.  Just drag it from the effects browser to your edit.

Edit: [Here's](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6aKxDC1rLtqbGxnZ2Z5WGZqb0U/edit?usp=sharing) one I created in Motion.  Delete the .xml extension that google adds to the filename; it should be called "SideBySideGradient.motr", not "SideBySideGradient.motr.xml"  Put this file at ~/Movies/Motion Templates.  If you don't already have a Motion Templates folder in your [home directory]/Movies, create one there, drop this in, and look for "SideBySideGradient" in your FCPX effects browser under the transitions category.  Drag this transition between two clips on your timeline, and VIOLA!

I realize that this is a pretty simple application which might not suit your needs exactly, which is why I encourage you to use motion and try it for yourself.  It's not hard!  If you need help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I added an explanation to my question. I need a transition between layers and not between clips in time. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that's what you meant.  The easiest solution is to use Motion.  Apple seriously shifted a lot of functionality over there to keep FCPX simple.  FCPX doesn't even have an 8 point garbage matte anymore.  Kind of a pain, imho.  Another alternative would be to bake the gradient into the alpha channel of Prores 4444 using another application.  Final cut Displays these alphas correctly, but doesn't let you edit them.  Apart from that, you might try kludging together a combination of the gradient generator & the keyer effect.  $50 for motion is your best bet, imho.

Comment: made one for you.  see answer above.